# Delete the contents of a workbook after a specific date

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening, all,

I'm currently in contract renegotiations and I have an excel sheet full of my own personal marketing and cost analysis information. This company has a history of waiting until contracts expire and then accessing "abandoned" data for their own end. I want to add a VBA code in the background so that, if I haven't deleted the VBA by a specific date, it will wipe the contents of the worksheets (none of this data is company data, it is all my own work). The sheets are held on both Excel and Sharepoint. I don't know more than basic VBA (like the file cannot be "saved as", etc) but would really like to avoid being shamelessly exploited. Can anyone make some code suggestions, please?

Comment: If you're storing your work on company equipment, you may struggle to argue ownership. But if we ignore your claim to ownership for a second - then I'd suggest the following: Make a ***password encrypted*** back-up somewhere (save it, zip/encrypt it), and then delete your original work. The longer you wait before doing this, the higher the chance of someone simply accessing an old back-up (built in to Windows and also SharePoint) and retrieving your data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below and it worked for me.

This code is pasted into ThisWorkbook in the VB Editor.

The VBA should be password protected.

If later you realise that this information is held over several workbooks, then they should be all emptied here, lest your ex-company get wise to this macro and try to circumvent it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim WS As Worksheet, wsBlank As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

If Now() > DateSerial(2022, 9, 4) Then
    Set wsBlank = wb.Sheets.Add
    
    For Each WS In wb.Sheets
        If WS.Name <> wsBlank.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            WS.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```